# Mongodb Data Login and Data Disappeared restart not helping

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I had a Mongodb database running on an Amazon ec2 instance(using Amazon Linux). It worked well for a while and then I got an authorization error when I tried to connect. I re added my user and and restarted the database, and almost all of the data was missing. What might have caused this and is there any way to get the data back?

I've tried restarting the database and running the recovery operation with mongodb.

Comment: Can you look into mongod log file and try to find some relevant error entries? Maybe it has been attacked by intruders and they changed your password and deleted data?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and sorry to hear about this problem. I have noted below what I would do in this situation, but obviously it all depends on your exact environment.

I would investigate the logs first, invoking Amazon support if necessary, to find out exactly what was happening at the time of the failure, because this may affect what you do next.

Ask yourself questions like:

- Is it possible that your data is still as you left it, but that the hostname you are using is now pointing to a different server?
- Is the data that *is* present very old (implying that the database has mysteriously gone back to an earlier state), or very new (implying that it has been cleared and is now filling up again), or neither of these (implying some sort of corruption)?
- Maybe there has been an application change that has corrupted the database?
- Does anyone else have access to the database, or to the server, in a way that would have permitted them to cause the problem (accidentally or otherwise)?

Then you will need to find out, from whoever set up the database and/or the server, where the backups are kept (whether they are Amazon ones or locally scripted ones) and how often they run, then, even if your recovery operation does not work, you will at least be able to restore the data to a known point. (Maybe there is a synchronised copy on another server, although that would probably have got corrupted too.)

Finally, it's obviously important to take any necessary steps to prevent the problem from recurring: harden the security, improve the backup regime, fix application bugs, etc.

Comment: It could also be the case that the mongo `dbPath` was chaged (somehow) so that all the persistent data is gone from Mongos memory